# how can I make the button appear

Tags: android

I'm new at developing app,I'm trying to develop app that make the users read with the voice thier emails so I want to add control bar that make them stop,slow or speed the reading

now i just want to know how to add button that appear with the user open his mail inbox

when I try this in usual way the button does not appear

```
public class Test1MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1_main);

        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        Intent intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

How can I make the button appear with the mail inbox ? I mean like a tool for the users in their inbox.

Comment: can you please make it more understandable?

Comment: post your xml as well.

Comment: what do you mean with `index`?

Comment: oh sorry Imean inbox

Answer (score 1):

So far, you are launching the intent when your activity starts.
You should create a Listener with the intent code and set it to your button like this:

```
public class Test1MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1_main);

        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks , but I dont mean that I want the button apear for the users with the mail inbox at the same time

Comment: So please explain yourself a little bit better